# Objective C - 2 Buttons of 8 should disappear when playing the same sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, audio

I have a question about buttons and sounds.

I have 8 buttons. They should be playing 1 of 4 soundfiles when loading. Each 2 buttons the same Soundfile. And if the same soundfile played at button two, button 1&2 shall disappear. I hope you understand my problem :)

Im now there, that buttons can play random soundfiles, but i want that each button get a random sound at start and this should never change in this view.

Hope for help!

**Edit: Here's the code**

```
int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 4; //random number from 0 to 3

NSLog(@"random sound number = %i", randomSoundNumber);

NSString *effectTitle;

switch (randomSoundNumber) {
    case 0:
        effectTitle = @"bell";
        break;
    case 1:
        effectTitle = @"brake";
        break;
    case 2:
        effectTitle = @"dog";
        break;
    case 3:
        effectTitle = @"bird";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

SystemSoundID soundID;

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: So you're basically programming "Memory" with sounds instead of Images.
Can you post your code and show us what you've already tried?

Comment: Yes thats right, you're smart :D

Comment: I don't know about objective-c, but you can create an array like this: `[sound1, sound1, sound2, sound2, ..., sound4]`. Afterwards, use a `shuffle` function to randomly sort that array. Then, assign the sounds: `button[0].sound = array[0]; button[1].sound = array[1];, ...`

Comment: Yes but then its always random every time i press the button. But i want it random generated at the begin and that its then fixed to each button?

Comment: You have to call that init-function only once when the game starts

Answer (score 0):

Create a mutable set and add 56 NSNumbers to it (0 to 55). Generate a random number r between 0 and 55 and get the rth number from the set. This represents your first pair of buttons. Remove this from the set, and repeat three more times, each time with a smaller set. You now have 4 numbers n between 0 and 55, each representing a pair of numbers (b1,b2).

```
b1 = n/7; // (integer divide)
b2 = (n-b1*10)/7;
b2 = b1==b2?b2+1;
```

Why 56? There are 64 permutations of 8 objects. There are 8 permutations that are repeated, so if you remove these you have 56 numbers left. These numbers map to the permutations 01, 02, ...,07,10,12,....
(where the dups have been removed).